# File open randomly doesn't work

Tags: python

I am using Python code(written by someone else) which basically scans a folder, and reads all the Wav files in it, and sends them to a Cloud Voice service. if there are "N" distinct folders, it runs this in parallel, by opening 'N" python instances. This is run on Win10 machine.

The code looks like:

```
try:
    for i in range(3):
        files = ""
        if wavEnding == ".wav":
            with open(fName+wavEnding, 'rb') as inf:
                inf.seek(40)
                s = inf.read(4)
                dLengt = struct.unpack("<I",s)
                tosend = inf.read(dLengt[0])
                files = [
                    ('file', ('request', json.dumps(ASRService), 'application/json; charset=UTF-8')),
                    ('file', ('audio', tosend, 'audio/L16; rate=16000; channels=1'))
                ]
except IOError as ierr:
    currentDT = datetime.datetime.now()
    with open(os.getcwd() + "\\sendUtterance.txt", "a") as aF:
        print "File: " + fName + wavEnding+" not found"
        aF.write(str(currentDT) + " " + fName + wavEnding+ " + not found\n")
        aF.close()
```

Now, every now and then, I can see "sendUtterance.txt" shows errors for missing files,for different folders, while I can clearly see that files are present in those folders (timing of errors and folders are random).
Below is snapshot of error for error file:
[image]

If there was something wrong with code, I would expect this to throw error for each file in each folder, bit it doesn't.
Could running this as parallel process, be straining/chocking the system, so that file open doesn't work? or is it something else? and what can I do for possible solution?

Comment: Whats the error exactly?

Comment: For one thing, you can log the actual error, instead of always assuming it's "file not found".

Comment: Or maybe the file name specified is/isn't absolute!

Comment: Jordon, so I should use exception other than IOError?

Comment: Catching `IOError` is fine, but you should log the contents of `ierr` instead of assuming it is always "file not found".  If you like you can have another catch of plain `Exception` as a safety net.

Comment: ok, so using  'ierr.errno'?

Comment: Can you add the relevant code that goes over the folders and files within the folder?